# Calculating pourbaix diagram of Fe-H2O system at different temperatures

Tags: thermodynamics, metallurgy, chemical-engineering, corrosion, nernst-equation

I have been trying to calculate the pourbaix diagram for Fe-H2O at different temperature for my high school research but I am facing a lot of problems. I have several question regarding the calculation of equations for the diagram.

**1) Horizontal line**

Correct me if I am wrong.

Finding the horizontal line for the diagram is not a problem. I have the standard electrode potential of the ion, lets consider the equation

**Fe3+ (aq) + e-  = Fe2+ (aq)**
(I should always consider the eqaution in reduction form right?)

and thus using Nernst equation, I get;

[image]

Now as I will be considering the concentration to be 10^-6, thus log 1 = 0. Thus,

The electrode potential will be equal to standard electrode potential of 0.771 for Fe2+.

Thus I get my horizontal line, Y = 0.771

**2. The vertical line.**

I am having issues here as thermodynamic properties like free energy, entropy, enthalpy are sensitive to temperature change.

I) Where do I find the standard thermodynamic properties of aq ions at 10^-6 M? The CDC handbook has the values for 1M.

II) Gibbs free energy for the formation of **Fe2O3** is mentioned as -742.2 kJ/mol. But some papers have mentioned it to be -8242 J/mol for the following equation

**2Fe3+ + 3H2O → Fe2O3 + 6H+**

So the gibbs free energy will vary for the compound depending upon the reactants, right? If so then how do I find the standard gibbs free energy at 25 degree C for;

**Fe(OH)2 + 2 H+  = Fe2+  + 2 H2O**

**Fe3O4 + 2e-  + 8 H+ = 3 Fe2+   + 4 H2O**

**Fe2O3 + 2e-  + 6H+  = 2Fe2+  + 3H2O**

Similarly the values for enthalpy and entropy will be different for different equations. Once I am able to find the standard enthalpy and entropy for these reactions at 25 degree C, I can use the following formulas to get enthalpy and entropy at desired temperature.

[image]

where heat capacity, C can be derived from the following formula (right?)

[image]

I search on google and there are different variations to this formulas, why? Also where can I find the values of a,b,c,d,e constands for iron. Do they change for every compound of iron or are same for all species of iron?

After I successfully, find all of these values I will be able to find the gibbs free energy at a given temperature by

[image]

Next, I can use

[image]

to find the equilibrium constant. All of this just to find the equilibrium constant for the reaction. Is there any other way to find K for the reaction at different temperatures?

After that I can finally calculate the pH or the X value for pourbaix diagram for the equation

[image]

using;

[image]

**3. Slope**

If I can figure out these 2 equations then the slope will be easier to do as it is just the combination of the above 2 equations. I will be using the following equation for finding the slope.

[image]

please let me know if there is an easier way to approach this problem. I would be really grateful if you could answer my questions as I do not have a supervisor to help me for a long time now and the deadline is coming close.

Comment: Is $\pu{10^{-6}}$ the concentration of both ions ? Why do you choose such small concentrations as $\pu{10^{-6}}$ M ? $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ ions are so sensitive to oxygen that at the tiniest traces of oxygen, some $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ ions  will be oxidized. And the ratio will change.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Yes for both the ions. I choose that because some research papers said that generally the species have a very small concentration of 10e-6. Should I consider 1M instead?

Comment: No ! $1$ M is too concentrated. Maximum solubility of iron(II) sulfate is $0.56$ M. I would choose $0.1$ M.

Comment: Can you help me with other problems